# HTML5 record audio to file

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-recording

What I ultimately want to do is record from the user's microphone, and upload the file to the server when they're done. So far, I've managed to make a stream to an  element with the following code:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio_preview");

navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}, function(stream) {
   audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}, onRecordFail);

var onRecordFail = function (e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

How do I go from that, to recording to a file?

Comment: http://danml.com/js/recaudio.js is a really short single-file lib (5kb) i cleaned up from code based on this blog post: http://typedarray.org/wp-content/projects/WebAudioRecorder/ unlike the other ones i found (some linked here) the usage is quite simple: recorder.start() and recorder.stop(fnCallbackToCatchWAV_URL)

Comment: From 2016: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820578/how-to-capture-audio-in-javascript

Comment: https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/ is instructive and has a working demo.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

There is a fairly complete recording demo available at:  http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

It allows you to record audio in the browser, then gives you the option to export and download what you've recorded.

You can view the source of that page to find links to the javascript, but to summarize, there's a `Recorder` object that contains an `exportWAV` method, and a `forceDownload` method.

Comment: That only works if you use Canary or have the flags set in configuration.

Comment: @Fibericon not anymore (: Stable Chrome does too now (Version 28.0.1500.71 Mac).

Comment: Which makes me very happy! Now I'm looking very intently at FF to catch up.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work properly on windows 8, the audio playback is silent. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the sample, it works fine on Windows 7 but I am unable to test at iPad, how can I?

Comment: It is fine when testing online. But if I save all the html files (js, png,...), it does not work locally.

Comment: I've tested the demo, it works fine in Chrome and Opera but there is issues with firefox (The microphone is recognized but not the sound)..
And for Safari and IE, they doesn't know how to handle that code

Comment: where can I have the complete code? I tried to extract it but not working in my local server (xampp)

Comment: Even their Github example folder not working on local. https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: The demo in this answer uses [mattdiamond's Recorder.js](https://addpipe.com/blog/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/).

Comment: This solution uses the deprecated createScriptProcessor.  It looks like this has been replaced by AudioWorklet, but I do not have an example to share.

Answer (score 44):

The code shown below is copyrighted to Matt Diamond and available for use under MIT license. The original files are here:

- http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html
- http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/js/recorderjs/recorderWorker.js

Save this files and use

```js
(function(window){

      var WORKER_PATH = 'recorderWorker.js';
      var Recorder = function(source, cfg){
        var config = cfg || {};
        var bufferLen = config.bufferLen || 4096;
        this.context = source.context;
        this.node = this.context.createScriptProcessor(bufferLen, 2, 2);
        var worker = new Worker(config.workerPath || WORKER_PATH);
        worker.postMessage({
          command: 'init',
          config: {
            sampleRate: this.context.sampleRate
          }
        });
        var recording = false,
          currCallback;

        this.node.onaudioprocess = function(e){
          if (!recording) return;
          worker.postMessage({
            command: 'record',
            buffer: [
              e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0),
              e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1)
            ]
          });
        }

        this.configure = function(cfg){
          for (var prop in cfg){
            if (cfg.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
              config[prop] = cfg[prop];
            }
          }
        }

        this.record = function(){
       
          recording = true;
        }

        this.stop = function(){
        
          recording = false;
        }

        this.clear = function(){
          worker.postMessage({ command: 'clear' });
        }

        this.getBuffer = function(cb) {
          currCallback = cb || config.callback;
          worker.postMessage({ command: 'getBuffer' })
        }

        this.exportWAV = function(cb, type){
          currCallback = cb || config.callback;
          type = type || config.type || 'audio/wav';
          if (!currCallback) throw new Error('Callback not set');
          worker.postMessage({
            command: 'exportWAV',
            type: type
          });
        }

        worker.onmessage = function(e){
          var blob = e.data;
          currCallback(blob);
        }

        source.connect(this.node);
        this.node.connect(this.context.destination);    //this should not be necessary
      };

      Recorder.forceDownload = function(blob, filename){
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
        var link = window.document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = filename || 'output.wav';
        var click = document.createEvent("Event");
        click.initEvent("click", true, true);
        link.dispatchEvent(click);
      }

      window.Recorder = Recorder;

    })(window);

    //ADDITIONAL JS recorderWorker.js
    var recLength = 0,
      recBuffersL = [],
      recBuffersR = [],
      sampleRate;
    this.onmessage = function(e){
      switch(e.data.command){
        case 'init':
          init(e.data.config);
          break;
        case 'record':
          record(e.data.buffer);
          break;
        case 'exportWAV':
          exportWAV(e.data.type);
          break;
        case 'getBuffer':
          getBuffer();
          break;
        case 'clear':
          clear();
          break;
      }
    };

    function init(config){
      sampleRate = config.sampleRate;
    }

    function record(inputBuffer){

      recBuffersL.push(inputBuffer[0]);
      recBuffersR.push(inputBuffer[1]);
      recLength += inputBuffer[0].length;
    }

    function exportWAV(type){
      var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
      var bufferR = mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength);
      var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
      var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
      var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });

      this.postMessage(audioBlob);
    }

    function getBuffer() {
      var buffers = [];
      buffers.push( mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength) );
      buffers.push( mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength) );
      this.postMessage(buffers);
    }

    function clear(){
      recLength = 0;
      recBuffersL = [];
      recBuffersR = [];
    }

    function mergeBuffers(recBuffers, recLength){
      var result = new Float32Array(recLength);
      var offset = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < recBuffers.length; i++){
        result.set(recBuffers[i], offset);
        offset += recBuffers[i].length;
      }
      return result;
    }

    function interleave(inputL, inputR){
      var length = inputL.length + inputR.length;
      var result = new Float32Array(length);

      var index = 0,
        inputIndex = 0;

      while (index < length){
        result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex];
        result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex];
        inputIndex++;
      }
      return result;
    }

    function floatTo16BitPCM(output, offset, input){
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset+=2){
        var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
        output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
      }
    }

    function writeString(view, offset, string){
      for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
      }
    }

    function encodeWAV(samples){
      var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
      var view = new DataView(buffer);

      /* RIFF identifier */
      writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
      /* file length */
      view.setUint32(4, 32 + samples.length * 2, true);
      /* RIFF type */
      writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
      /* format chunk identifier */
      writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
      /* format chunk length */
      view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
      /* sample format (raw) */
      view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
      /* channel count */
      view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
      /* sample rate */
      view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
      /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
      view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
      /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
      view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
      /* bits per sample */
      view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
      /* data chunk identifier */
      writeString(view, 36, 'data');
      /* data chunk length */
      view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

      floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

      return view;
    }
```

```html
<html>
     <body>
      <audio controls autoplay></audio>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="recorder.js"> </script>
                    <fieldset><legend>RECORD AUDIO</legend>
      <input onclick="startRecording()" type="button" value="start recording" />
      <input onclick="stopRecording()" type="button" value="stop recording and play" />
                    </fieldset>
      <script>
       var onFail = function(e) {
        console.log('Rejected!', e);
       };

       var onSuccess = function(s) {
        var context = new webkitAudioContext();
        var mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(s);
        recorder = new Recorder(mediaStreamSource);
        recorder.record();

        // audio loopback
        // mediaStreamSource.connect(context.destination);
       }

       window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
       navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

       var recorder;
       var audio = document.querySelector('audio');

       function startRecording() {
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
         navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, onSuccess, onFail);
        } else {
         console.log('navigator.getUserMedia not present');
        }
       }

       function stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.exportWAV(function(s) {
                                
                                  audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(s);
        });
       }
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @ Ankit Araynya you provide download code for this audio record file .

Comment: @Ankit Araynya this helpful for me. i stuck on this problem since 3 days with heavy googling

Comment: i am in need to change the name of blob that is saving. because i am sending blob to server using ajax with form data and while getting file name its giving blob. Is there anything you can help me with that.

Comment: @Jennifer you can change the name in server side

Comment: I'm inclined to drop a downvote here today, because ScriptProcessorNode does processing on the main thread, and will be blocked by layout computations, GC, and other similar stuff, leading to glitches even with high buffer sizes. It's fine in a dead simple demo or as a proof of concept, but not in any reasonably complex real app.

Answer (score 31):

**Update** now Chrome also supports [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API from v47. The same thing to do would be to use it( guessing native recording method is bound to be faster than work arounds), the API is really easy to use, and you would find tons of answers as to how to upload a blob for the server.

[**Demo**](https://mido22.github.io/MediaRecorder-sample/) - would work in Chrome and Firefox, intentionally left out pushing blob to server...

[**Code Source**](https://github.com/Mido22/MediaRecorder-sample)

---

<s>Currently, there are three ways to do it:</s>

1. as `wav`[ all code client-side, uncompressed recording], you can check out --> [Recorderjs](http://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs). Problem: file size is quite big, more upload bandwidth required.
2. as `mp3`[ all code client-side, compressed recording], you can check out --> [mp3Recorder](http://github.com/Mido22/mp3Recorder). Problem: personally, I find the quality bad, also there is this licensing issue.
3. as `ogg` [ client+ server(`node.js`) code, compressed recording, infinite hours of recording without browser crash ], you can check out --> [recordOpus](http://github.com/Mido22/recordOpus), either only client-side recording, or client-server bundling, the choice is yours.

   ogg recording example( only firefox):

   ```
   var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
   mediaRecorder.start();  // to start recording.    
   ...
   mediaRecorder.stop();   // to stop recording.
   mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
       // do something with the data.
   }
   ```

   [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z7xcuxm/) for ogg recording.

Comment: Chromium "script.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is not a function"

Comment: @dikirill you must be using a server(it works locally), it won't work with files, also it does not work on workers(I had much headache in this), if you don't know how to make a server you should install https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

Comment: excellent answer, i find your script easy and simple. however, i was trying to change the start button to do the job of request stream also, any ideas? https://github.com/Mido22/MediaRecorder-sample/issues/6

Answer (score 16):

The question is very old and many of the answers are not supported in the current version of the browser. I was trying to create the audio recorder using simple `html`, `css`, and `js`. I further went on to use the same code in electron to make a cross platform application.

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Recorder App</title>
    
  </head>
  <h2>Recorder App</h2>
  <p>
    <button type="button" id="record">Record</button>
    <button type="button" id="stopRecord" disabled>Stop</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <audio id="recordedAudio"></audio>        
  </p>

  <script> 
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
    .then(stream => {handlerFunction(stream)})

    function handlerFunction(stream) {
      rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        if (rec.state == "inactive"){
          let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/mp3'});
          recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          recordedAudio.controls=true;
          recordedAudio.autoplay=true;
          sendData(blob)
          }
        }
      }
    
    function sendData(data) {}
      record.onclick = e => {
        record.disabled = true;
        record.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
        stopRecord.disabled=false;
        audioChunks = [];
        rec.start();
        }
      stopRecord.onclick = e => {
        record.disabled = false;
        stop.disabled=true;
        record.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        rec.stop();
        }
  </script>
</html>
```

The above code works in Windows 10, Mac, Linux, and obviously, on both google chrome and firefox.

Comment: How to upload that blob to a server?

Comment: There are some mistakes in this. For example line 12 id=recordedAudio, there are no quotes around the variable name.

Comment: @CSchwarz - awesome, but just tap edit and fix!

Answer (score 15):

This is a simple JavaScript sound recorder and editor. You can try it.

https://www.danieldemmel.me/JSSoundRecorder/

Can **download** from here

https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Appropriately, the first link provided is dead - subdomain rerouting issue. The updated link is [http://www.danieldemmel.me/JSSoundRecorder/](http://www.danieldemmel.me/JSSoundRecorder/) but the example doesn't work anyways (Chrome 60) because the site doesn't support HTTPS. Going to  [the secure version](https://www.danieldemmel.me/JSSoundRecorder/) and bypassing the security warning does allow the demo to work though.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **Recordmp3js** from GitHub to achieve your requirements. You can record from user's microphone and then get the file as an mp3. Finally upload it to your server.

I used this in my demo. There is a already a sample available with the source code by the author in this location :
https://github.com/Audior/Recordmp3js

The demo is here:
http://audior.ec/recordmp3js/

But currently works only on Chrome and Firefox.

Seems to work fine and pretty simple. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your demo doesn't work in Chromium, console shows warning: getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins.

Comment: Try running it on http, via localhost or on a live server?

Comment: `getUserMedia()` only works on secure origins (https, localhost) [since Chrome 47](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc)

Comment: Demo link is broken.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a gitHub project that does just that.

It records audio from the browser in mp3 format, and it automatically saves it to the webserver.
https://github.com/Audior/Recordmp3js

You can also view a detailed explanation of the implementation:
http://audior.ec/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/

Comment: Based on that project and article I wrote another small tool that refactored the used code and enhanced it to be able to use multiple recorders on one page. It can be found under: https://github.com/icatcher-at/MP3RecorderJS

Answer (score 5):

Stream audio in realtime without waiting for recording to end:
https://github.com/noamtcohen/AudioStreamer

This streams PCM data but you could modify the code to stream mp3 or [Speex](https://github.com/jpemartins/speex.js/)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need **wav file format**, you can use this npm package without any changes. https://www.npmjs.com/package/extendable-media-recorder

```js
import { MediaRecorder, register } from 'extendable-media-recorder';
import { connect } from 'extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder';

await register(await connect());

const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/wav' });
```