# Is it possible to record sound playing in browser or speaker in javascript or by any scripting language?

Tags: javascript, audio-recording

I have used html audio tags for playing multiple mp3 file in browser. I want to know if it is possible to record these mp3's into a single mp3 file in javascript(specifically)?. Or even if any module which can help me record these playing mp3's.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no.

It *is* possible to work with audio in JS but probably not in the way you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file) for more info.

I don't know what exactly you're trying to do but it seems like you would need to do it server-side, and even that would take effort to achieve (Since you would need to find a library that could merge multiple MP3s into a single file and then serve that as a download to the user. This would also require you to know *how* to install such software and make it available to your server-side code).

Comment: Actually, merging mp3s into a single file is easy: you can just concatenate them together. It isn't a perfect result, but it is good enough.