# Audio processing in php

Tags: php

I would like to do a audio processing in php. That means records a voice and save it in as .mp3 file.

1. I want to know is it possible in php?
2. Are there any libraries you know of that could help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to record audio from a browser, then the answer is No. You need to look at Adobe Flash or something similar.

Comment: I just want to know is it possible in php.That is record a audio and save it in as mp3 format.

Comment: You can try a HTML5 based solution. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16498273/3461549)