# Recording audio in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, voice-recording

On an application I'm working on I want a robust way of recording audio and uploading it to S3. I don't really see any good solutions out there. Would like some help on how I could go about it. I was initially looking at using the getUserMedia() Javascript API but it doesn't work on Safari.

Comment: Sounds like more of a JavaScript/HTML5/Flash question than a Rails question. This looks like it would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file.

Comment: Did you end up finding a gem for this?

Comment: @alex_milhouse No did not.