# How to record audio in format of mp3/m4a JavaScript- recorder.js

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, audio-recording, recorder.js

In recorderjs `rec.exportWAV([callback][, type])` is used to generate a Blob object containing the recorded audio in WAV format.

But the WAV file is taking large space, for 30sec it is approximately 1mb. So I want to record the audio in format of mp3/m4a which takes less space.

Is there any way to record audio in format of mp3/m4a.

Comment: please to feedback on this

Answer (score 2):

**Recorder.js does NOT support encoding captured audio as mp3.**

It can only record 16 bit mono or stereo uncompressed pcm as wav.

To halve the size you could record mono sound instead of 2 channel/stereo using `numChannels:1` in the Recorder.js constructor like this:

`var rec = new Recorder(source,{numChannels:1})`

`numChannels` is an undocumented feature of Recorder.js (the library is not maintained anymore).

Source: https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/

**To record to mp3 you can use:**

1. [WebAudioRecorder.js](https://blog.addpipe.com/using-webaudiorecorder-js-to-record-audio-on-your-website/) which includes an *asm.js* version of the [LAME mp3 encoder](http://lame.sourceforge.net/)
2. [vmsg](https://blog.addpipe.com/recording-mp3-audio-in-html5-using-vmsg-a-webassembly-library-based-on-lame/) which includes a WebAssembly version of the [LAME mp3 encoder](http://lame.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

i think  you should check this link :
[HTML5 record audio to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file)

here u can change the audio type like this :
  type = type || config.type || 'audio/wav';

Answer (score -2):

You can change the format of the recording by mentioning the format in exportWAV function, as follows:

```
recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
                callback(blob);

                // create WAV download link using audio data blob
                // createDownloadLink();

                // Clear the Recorder to start again !
                recorder.clear();
            }, "audio/mp3");
```

I have came to the above solution for the following [link](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/499/how-to-record-and-export-audio-wav-and-mp3-using-recorder-js-in-html5).

Comment: As far as I know, it only changes the mime type, it's not doing any compression to the recorded data.

Comment: When you send `audio/mpeg` instead of `audio/wav` to `exportWAV()` it just (erroneously) changes the MIME type of the wav Blob, it does not magically turn on mp3 encoding - you need the LAME mp3 encoding library for that.

The tutorial you're quoting is incorrect in this regard. I've recently written an [up to date Recorder.js tutorial](https://addpipe.com/blog/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/).