# Convert a .wav file format to .mp3 using recorder.js mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Tags: javascript, recorder.js

Trying to capture raw audio from a user using [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/dist/recorder.js) and upload it to a server, I came across [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/499/how-to-record-and-export-audio-wav-and-mp3-using-recorder-js-in-html5) site and it instructed to call function *stopRecording()* with a second argument and also to change **_AudioFormat** from "audio/wav" to "audio/mpeg".

Code snippet from my view:

```
$(".transBtn").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("transRecording")){
                //var _AudioFormat = "audio/mp3";

                var AudioFormat = "audio/mpeg";

                stopRecording(function(AudioBLOB){

                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(AudioBLOB);


                    $(".downloadAud").attr("href" , url);
                    $(".downloadAud").attr("download" , "myRec.mp3");

                    var l = document.getElementById('save');  // save is the id of anchor tag
                    l.click();
                }, AudioFormat);
            }
            else {
                startRecording();
                //alert("Live Recording");
            }
        })
```

Sorry to take your time but I'm unable to download the file in .mp3 format. I would be very glad if you helped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That site is wrong. Recorder.js can only record pcm/wav audio. This (duplicate) question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50931101/813988) including mp3 encoding solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to record audio in format of mp3/m4a JavaScript- recorder.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138865/how-to-record-audio-in-format-of-mp3-m4a-javascript-recorder-js)