# Javascript addEventListener not working with for loop

Tags: javascript

**Edit:** Topic has been marked as duplicate. I just wanted to say that im not happy with the answers of the other post. The accepted answer uses a not so nice way of dealing with such problem. Apart from that I made it clear that I read all those posts before and have difficulties understanding that particular problem area in javascript.

I dont get this at all. I really do a lot of reading, especially about closures but I dont get this...im on it for hours. Why does the following code fail to work? Im absolutely lost now and I need someone who could really point out how I can overcome situations like these where my index fails to be recognized within my event function.

How does this work? My addEventListener just wont work since the index is only recognized outside of it.

```
var lastResponse;
var alpha = document.getElementById('alpha');
var httpRequest;

function initAjax(url) {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open('POST', url, true);
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  httpRequest.send();

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
        var response = httpRequest.responseText;
        document.getElementById("omega").innerHTML = response;
        fn();
    }
  }
}

alpha.addEventListener("click", function() {
  initAjax("test.php");
});

var x = document.getElementById("omega").children;

function fn() {
    for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++){
        console.log(x.length);
        document.getElementById("omega").addEventListener("click", function(event){
            hello(i, event);
        }, false);
    }
}

function hello(index, event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget.children[index]);
}
```

**Updated code**

- Ajax gets content with their respective divs
- When request is completed javascript injects the returned data from the server to omega.
- Omega has children.
- Now I want to click on one of those children and get their index.

Comment: can you explain what you expect to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: Maybe try document.getElementById("omega").addEventListener("click", function(event){
            hello(i, event);
        }.bind({}), false);

Comment: @blessenm did you mean `.bind(this)`?

Comment: `#omega` is the only element that's an `event.target` ,is in a loop,  why ? I think you need to include the HTML, because I'm having a hard time trying to visualize a `button#omega`? These `children` of  `#omega` are what and how many?

Comment: @Fabricator I added more details

Comment: @MatthewHerbst well I just really read the topic name and my guess was the function may need to be cloned. So bind should do that. Just a guess.

Comment: @zer00ne Should be 11

Comment: @blessenm doesnt work or I did it wrong. Added more info in my question

Comment: The loop in fn() makes no sense to me: for each child of #omega you bind a listener to #omega itself, each of which returns the index of the original target of the event? Is that intended? Why Not bind to the children directly?

Comment: @Wortex17 that is intended. The function fn is called when ajax completed so that it can read x.length which is the length of the children from omega

Comment: Since I don't realy know what your failing result is, I am going to assume that you get "undefined" echoed. Beware that hello(i, event); evaluates once the callback is being called, at which point the list is likely to have been iterated and i will be at x.length

Comment: @Wortex17 yes I do. Let me check again

Comment: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined

Comment: @asperger I think it would a lot more easier if you could create a failing bin on jsbin.com. Cause ur use case doesn't seem straightforward and everyones guessing or assuming. You could simulate ajax by just return some data in setTimeout.

Comment: @Asperger Does this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/rg9hsv1h/

Comment: @blessenm here a sandbox for you https://jsfiddle.net/9wLhqfnf/  .

Comment: @Asperger is this what u need https://jsfiddle.net/9wLhqfnf/1/

Comment: @JoshCrozier somewhat but it display all the indexes instead of just the index of the one clicked

Comment: @blessenm heck yes :D

Comment: @blessenm maybe post an answer explaining it abit. This is interesting

Comment: @Asperger I cant. this question is now marked as duplicate. Well I just get the 'currentTarget' which is parent element and the 'target' element which is clicked element and use a array indexOf method. But in actual code u may need to do some checks to make sure what the clicked element is if you nest other tags in a item.

Comment: @blessenm you really deserve it, I think marking the post was a bit unfair. The other post is really outdated. Your answer really is up to date and clean.

Comment: @blessenm can you explain that part? [].indexOf.call. This looks like a very pro thing to do. Nice.

Comment: @blessenm: cool solution.

Comment: @AhmetCetin yes but no one mentioned how to do this with a for loop.

Comment: @Asperger Well dom elements look like arrays but are not actual arrays. So they dont get the array methods in Array.prototype. So to do array operations on a DOM we use the call method on an empty array but pass the element to be used as the context. ([].indexOf.call(el, ortherEl)). es6 now has Array.from which can be used to create an array from array like elements like DOM.

Comment: @Asperger: [].indexOf.call is shortcut of Array.prototype.indexOf function. The first  argument you're passing item is the bound object, the second argument is the item you're searching in that array. + explanation of blessenm why you need to use Array.prototype call instead of alert(evt.currentTarget.children.indexOf(evt.target));

Comment: @blessenm what about this? http://jsfiddle.net/PjweJ/113/

Comment: @AhmetCetin I think im close to making it work with a normal for loop but im not sure http://jsfiddle.net/PjweJ/113/

Comment: Actually, as long as you don't want to add event listener to each children, you don't need a loop. @blessenm's solution is pretty clean, and should do the job, as long as you don't have other elements under the "omega" div other than added through the ajax call.

Comment: @Asperger Is this what u need cause my brain is hardwired to avoid adding listeners in a loop. So im kinda fighting it. http://jsfiddle.net/PjweJ/118/

Comment: @blessenm am I pushing you over to the dark side? man sorry haha. Hey im giving some bounty when im eligible since all those good answers were yours. I think I might even have some open question somewhere. Just post something there later (anything) and ill give you the points :D

Comment: @Asperger no probs. Happy to start my year by helping out.

Comment: @blessenm wrong link. Hang on

Comment: @blessenm damn 18 hours. Ah, got to find an older post

Comment: @blessenm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502069/saving-sounds-played-in-sequence-as-one-audio-file  there I activated a 150 bounty. Again thanks : )

Comment: @blessenm arent you getting the bounty? Oh, look at my implementation which works as well: http://jsfiddle.net/PjweJ/119/

Comment: @Asperger Ya ur codes fine. But its doing more work by looping the children for every click. This is the most I could simplify. http://jsfiddle.net/PjweJ/121/

Answer (score 1):

As this question marked as duplicate before @blessenm adds his answer, I'm just rewriting my answer so that his elegant solution will be visible to someone looking in this question in the future. I've posted different answer before the question was closed, so I'm still able to edit my answer. All credits to @blessenm:

```
function start() {
  omega.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    alert([].indexOf.call(evt.currentTarget.children, evt.target)); 
  }, false);
}
```

[].indexOf is shortcut of Array.prototype.indexOf function. The first argument you're passing is the context, the second argument is the item you're searching in that array. DOM elements array-like objects but are not actual arrays therefore they don't have the array methods in Array.prototype - that's why you cannot use alert(evt.currentTarget.children.indexOf(evt.target)). To do array operations on a DOM we use the call method of Array prototype.

Comment: I dont want to add an event listener to every child which is why ive done this event.currentTarget.children[index] which is far better

Comment: ok, then why you keep var getting # of children outside of your fn() function? at the time you call fn (async), x equals to the number of children under omega before you call fn. i updated the answer, can you check?

Comment: Im getting undefined

Comment: Which line do you get undefined? I changed the code a bit passing number of divs under omega as argument to function fn, so you don't need var x = document.getElementById("omega").children;
can you check if it works?

Comment: Pls check again, using forEach loop should handle the closure problem.

Comment: I would like to give you an additional bounty of 150 reputation if you could also show the "redundant way" using a for loop and bind just for the sake of learning.

Comment: I will do that, but can it tomorrow? Promise I will post it.It's 7am here now, staying all night :)

Comment: Sure, no problem : )

Comment: @AhmetCetin I've also modified the code to handle loops. http://jsfiddle.net/PjweJ/118/

Comment: @blessenm: the first requirement in the question was, not to add event listener to children individually, so the latest solution of Asperger is legit. Asperger, as I see you figured out, the solution :)