# Record Voice using symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, voice

I want to record voice suing symfony, the user clic record and the script start recording the voice and the file will be saved in the user directory

I ask if there are a bundle for recording voice using symfony?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way you could handle recording audio from PHP, server-side. That must be the reason why there are no bundles to handle this in Symfony, because Packagist is mostly a server-side package registry.

You should instead investigate options of recording the audio on the client side (perhaps, using JavaScript, [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file) might be useful). If you have a native (Android, iOS, desktop) client as well, you should then look for libraries that allow recording audio on these platforms.

And on server side, basically, all you have to do is somehow implement file uploads for files that your client would record. The [cookbook entry on handling file uploads with Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html) might come in handy.