# play audio with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audio-streaming

I am trying to play audio in an html file:

```
var soundFile = document.createElement("audio");
soundFile.preload = "auto";
var src = document.createElement("source");
src.src = url_of_mp3_file;
soundFile.appendChild(src);
soundFile.load();
soundFile.play();
```

It works, but i have some latency. I think this is because it needs some time to download full audio file (i am on a local Ethernet network).

Is there a better way to do that ? I mean for example, is it possible to pre-download all my audio files in browser local storage and then play on demand files from this location ?

** EDIT **

And i want to play 2 mono files at the same time: One file on Left channel and the other on right channel.

Thanks

Comment: Please refer -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816266/saving-audio-to-localstorage-for-playback

Comment: See my edit, i have forget something, my question is different

Comment: Web Audio API allows control of left or right channel for rendering ... I take it you want to avoid other option of pre-processing both channels into one media file prior to rendering ?