# Record wav audio with specific parameters using javascript or html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Im trying some javascript codes to record wav sound, for example I tried this example:

http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

That I found in this post:

[HTML5 record audio to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file)

But I need to configure this attributes:

- Sampling Rate: 8000 Hz
- Bit Resolution: 16 (L16)
- Encoding: PCM linear (LPCM)
- Audio channel: Mono

This is not a duplicated post. The difference is that I need to generate the sound with specific configuration, like I said. I didn't find any example setting this parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sampling you want with the [`sampleRate` constraint](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#def-constraint-sampleRate).

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: {sampleRate: 8000}})
```

Native PCM encoding is entirely up to the browser, but PCM is simple enough that, given the stream, you can certainly implement it yourself.

Comment: as of Jan 2020, No browser support this.

Comment: Really ?
Console chrome : navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints(); shows True for it. Plus https://caniuse.com/#search=sampleRate