# Javascript converter to .wav

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in need of a way to convert my code to .wav and I can't seem to figure out where.
I have an audio script that records from the microphone and is saved as so:

```
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
```

Is there any way I can use any of these libraries to convert the audio to .wav?
If you need any more info let me know.
how the audio chunks are encoded:

```
const audioChunks = []
mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
    audioChunks.push(event.data);
});
```

Comment: How are the `audioChunks` encoded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 record audio to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file)