# Record the audio voice in Angular 2 and convert into .wav file

Tags: angular, recordrtc

I am using Angular 2. I want to record the audio voice from any web browser and convert the audio voice into .wav file.

I tried to record the audio voice from Record WebRTC function. but not able to convert .wav file which I required.

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

The .wav file will have below properties.

```
AudioBitRate = 128000
AudioChannelCount = 1
AudioSampleRate = 8000
BitsPerSample = 16
```

Help me guys If you are familiar with problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file

Comment: This is the Javascript code.

Comment: Hi Maneesh, Have you got the solution. I'm also searching the same thing. If youu got the solution, Kindly reply me

Comment: @A.Sakkeer Yes, I found the solution. but not from WeBRTC function. I using record js function.

Comment: Can you explain it briefly. How to use RecordJs in to my angular 2 application. Can you send the solution via email or something.

Comment: Yeah, Actually its a big solution, I can send you via email. Send me your email.

Comment: Hi Maneesh, Can you send the solution?. I hold the requirement for some reason. Now, They need the requirement. i think i completed. But I lost my code backups.  Can you help me.