# I need to implement Audio recording feature in web/mobile app with cross platform support

Tags: html, audio-recording

In one of my project i need to implement the feature of audio recording in both web/mobile inclusive of android/IOS support.

I have surfed in online and came across the below methodologies which will help to fulfill my need

Html Media capture

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*" capture>
```

This works only in android device.Opens the default recorder in android. Whereas in windows it opens file explorer and in IOS it opens camera instead of audio recorder

So we thought of trying different solution and we came across

```
navigator.getUserMedia
```

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio/

related code in online and we tried with a sample to cross check in all platforms. It works as expected in windows/android device platform but in IOS we came across below error

**not allowed error: the request is no allowed by user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission**

Guide some better solutions to achieve in cross platform without any issues.

Comment: Can i get any comments

Comment: There is a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file