# recording voice in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mediarecorder

I have got a Vue.js project and I need to record voice in that.
I have written some code and it works in that users can listen to their recorded voice, but I have got a problem: I would like to allow users to download their voice but when they click on the download they receive a .txt encoded file.

These are my functions for starting and stopping recording:

```
  startRecord(){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      this.mediaRecorder.start(1000);
      const self = this
      this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event:any) {
        self.audioChunks.push(event.data);
      }
    });
  }

  stopRecord(){
    const self = this
    this.mediaRecorder.stop();
    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(self.audioChunks);
      self.recordedVoice = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob)
    });
  }
```

and I pass `self.recordVoice` to the audio component like this:

```
<audio controls class="" >
 <source :src="recordedVoice"  type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file

Comment: https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/js/recorderjs/recorder.js